# Trying to set text alignment in python using Tkinter and scrolled text

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to set the text to be placed in the center or a ScrolledText widget. How is this done?
I have tried setting justify=center  but that gives "Unknown option "-justify"
What else can I do. Here is my code if it helps

```
#Gui
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
from tkinter import *
def center_window(width=300, height=200):
    # get screen width and height
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    # calculate position x and y coordinates
    x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))



root=Tk()
root.title("Writing is hard!") 
center_window(1200,600)

heading = Label(root, text="Welcome to the app which checks your content for you!", font=("arial",30,"bold"), fg="steelblue")
label1=Label(root, text="Please type in your article: ", font=("arial",20,"bold"), fg="lightgreen")
ArticleTextBox = tkst.ScrolledText(width=100, height=20, justify='CENTER')
def do_it():
    article=ArticleTextBox.get(0.0,tk.END)
    print("Hello "+name.get())
    print(article)
work= Button(root, text="work", width=30,height=5,bg="lightblue",command=do_it)

#Puts everything on screen
heading.pack()
label1.pack()
ArticleTextBox.pack()
work.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you're adding anything at all to the text box.

Comment: Thanks Bryan but that is supposed to be the case. This is because the user of the program will be typing into the ScrolledText, a bit like a word processor.

Answer (score 2):

`justify` is an attribute of a text tag. You can apply a tag to all the text, then set the `justify` attribute on that tag.

```
ArticleTextBox.insert("end", "hello\nworld!", ("centered",))
ArticleTextBox.tag_configure("centered", justify="center")
```

---

By the way, in your code you use the index `0.0` which is an invalid index. Tkinter will accept it, but technically it's invalid. Text indexes are strings, not floating point numbers, and the first line starts at 1 (one), not zero. So, `0.0` should be `"1.0"`.